# "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" when trying to run electron

Tags: node.js, gulp, electron, native, electron-builder

I got the following error when I was trying to run electron.

```
App threw an error during load
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:26
    at req_ (/path/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/path/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:12)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:12)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/node_modules/fstream/lib/reader.js:4:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:12)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/node_modules/fstream/fstream.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:12)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/node_modules/unzip2/lib/extract.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:12)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/node_modules/unzip2/unzip.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735:32)
```

I looked through some similar reported cases, it seems like I need to use node version prior to 10.
But I tried 3 node versions: v8.16.1 (npm v6.4.1), v10.17.0 (npm v6.11.3), v13.2.0 (npm v6.13.1).
All returned me the same error.

Has anyone faced this before?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same error from the module loader trying to start a project with `electron .`.  Had this problem earlier without gulp when doing `npm i` and solved by installing updated node version in a cleaned directory.  Not sure what to do here besides fresh node modules folder and package lock file with npm clean, but that didn't help.  May be using an old version of graceful-fs through some dependency chain to natives from unzip seems to be a common problem now, replacing with unzipper seemed to help the project at least.